# Sort List of SelectListItem with LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting

I'm trying to sort a List of SelectListItem with LINQ with no success.

```
 For Each item In query
            brandCategoryList.Add(New SelectListItem With {
                            .Text = FriendlyCategory(item),
                            .Value = item
                          })
        Next
        brandCategoryList.OrderBy(Function(m) m.Text)
```

What am I doing wrong? The results are returned in original order as if the OrderBy function was not called. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code seems to be correct, which is exactly the problem? I mean, what are the actual and desired outputs?

Comment: OrderBy doesn't sort the list, it returns an ordered IEnuemrable

Comment: Yes, OrderBy does not edit the source list. You may want to create a new one `brandCategoryList = brandCategoryList.OrderBy(Function(m) m.Text).ToList()`

Comment: See my answer for an alternative in-place sorting method

Comment: brandCategoryList = brandCategoryList.OrderBy(Function(m) m.Text).ToList()
returned the following error:                                                    Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,System.String]' to type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the list in place with `Sort()`

```
brandCategoryList.Sort(Function(a, b) a.Text < b.Text)
```

Comment: This worked but returned the sorted list in Descending order.  Hmmn.  Now to change it to Ascending?

Comment: Just reversed order to sort in Ascending order

    brandCategoryList.Sort(Function(a, b) b.Text > a.Text)

THANKS to all who helped!

Comment: Sorry, I used `>` instead of `<`. My fault, I fixed the answer for future reference, thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 2):

For me the easiest way to sort a SelectItemList using Linq is:

```
brandCategoryList.OrderBy(x => x.Text);
```

If you want sort by Text.

If you want sort by Value, is the same but x.Value:

```
brandCategoryList.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
brandCategoryList = query.Select(Function(x) new SelectListItem With {
                                             .Text = FriendlyCategory(item),
                                             .Value = item}).OrderBy(Function(m) m.Text).ToList();
```